# Track WordPress Signups with Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I would like to track WordPress user signups/registration using Google Analytics.

I've done this with other platforms before but for some reasons it's not working on WordPress.

1- I set my Goal URL to: /wp-login.php?checkemail=registered (that's the landing URL fir a success sign up)

2- Match Type: "Exact Match"

3- Goal Funnel Step 1: /wp-login.php?action=register (that's the Registration form URL)

I have couple of sign ups lately but Google Analytics didn't track them.

Anything help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How have you set up Google Analytics? Using a plugin?

Comment: Thanks @martinCzerwi... your suggestion gave me a big clue. Inside Yoast Google Analytics plugin, there's an option that says "Add tracking to the login and registration forms:", it was unchecked so that's why tracking wasn't working. I checked it and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Great. I was wondering if yoast was tracking the forms, but I didn't have the time, to check all the code, or try the plugin myself. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your GA code is even on the registration page? Even though I have my GA code in my header in all my pages WP left it out and I had to manually add it to the Registration Pages.